# Boolean members having true value by default in .NET remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, marshalbyrefobject

I am using .NET Remoting. I have a class which has some pubilc boolean members and set them to false at the time of declaration itself. This class inherits from MarshalByRefObject class.

When I access this class object in the client app, all these boolean members are true.
How is this happening ?

Comment: Are you accessing fields? or properties? Can we see the declarations impacted?

Comment: I don't think that this is a "known issue", so a *minimum working example* would be required...